# SQL, get results for something happening for a number of times consecutively

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

How can I get the result of a something happening 10 times consecutively in SQL?

Example -  I am trying to query for results, in this case, in donations.

The donor needs to have donated for the past ten consecutive years. so each year between 2004 and 2014.  If they missed one year, they can not be included.

So right now, im selecting from a gift table - GIFT

GIFT has attributes of yr_code , id (to identify who its from), and a gift_amt

```
SELECT gift_amt FROM gift WHERE yr_code = '2014'
```

but i want to efficiently do this for 10 consecutive years.

essentially right now it is written with an exists clause to go through all the years.  So it goes through everything saying if there exists a donation in 2014, good, exists a donation in 2013, good. etc...

```
     select 'x' from agbgift where 
     agbgift_fisc_code = '2014' and rownum = 1 and 
            ( exists 
                    ( select 'x' from agbgift where
                     agbgift_fisc_code = '2013' and 
                     agbgift_pidm = aprdclb_pidm 
                     ) 

            )
                    and 
            ( exists 
                    ( select 'x' from agbgift where
                     agbgift_fisc_code = '2012' and 
                     agbgift_pidm = aprdclb_pidm 
                     ) 
            ) 

          ..... this goes on for the years.
```

This is code previously written that i am trying to edit and condense.  Sorry for all the confusion, first time on here.  Thanks for the patience.

Comment: Please include schema of your tables.

Comment: so right now, im selecting from a gift table

GIFT has attributes of yr_code and id (to identify who its from) and a gift_amt

ex - SELECT gift_amt FROM gift WHERE yr_code = '2014' 
 but i want to efficiently do this for 10 consecutive years.

Comment: @mare630 don't post updates as comments. Use the *edit* link and include your updates in your question

Comment: ok sorry... didnt realize.

Comment: You've got this question tagged [mysql], [sql] (perhaps intended to have used [sql-server]?), and [oracle]. So, which database are you actually using, as that may affect the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question doesn't make a lot of sense... theres a few things I can think of for this...

but from what I understand you want something like this

```
SELECT gift_amt 
FROM gift
WHERE id IN
(   SELECT id 
    FROM
    (   SELECT *, @b := if(@a = yr_code, @b +1, 1) as num_yr, @a := yr_code
        FROM gift 
        WHERE yr_code > 2004 AND yr_code <= 2014 
        ORDER BY id, yr_code
    )t
    WHERE num_yr = 1
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 10
)
```

the inner query says give me the id of people that meet the requirements of ... the year they donated was between 04 and 14 (not including 04 because that would be 11 years) and have donated once per year

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9458f7/1)

The demo I posted is just the inner query but if you look at what its returning and the data that the table is running off of you will see that for id 1 the criteria is met meaning it has a donation in each year, id 2 even though there are multiple donations its not in every year so it doesn't get returned.

### BONUS:

if you want to get the total amount someone has donated in the past 10 years then just use SUM()

```
SELECT SUM(gift_amt) 
FROM gift
WHERE id IN
( .... )
```

if you want to get the total amount this year donated use an additional filter in the outer query's WHERE

```
SELECT SUM(gift_amt) 
FROM gift
WHERE id IN
( .... )
AND yr_code = 2014
```

if you want to get the largest donation still meeting the last 10 years criteria then use MAX

```
SELECT MAX(gift_amt) 
FROM gift
WHERE id IN
( .... )
AND yr_code = 2014 -- if you want it to be the current years greatest gift amount
```

Comment: @mare630 glad I can help! does this solve your problem?